# calculate survival probability and expected payout

Tags: r, survival, actuarial-science

I have data taken from [here](https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/birthsdeathsandmarriages/lifeexpectancies/datasets/nationallifetablesunitedkingdomreferencetables). Let us look at one specific column qx for female up to the age of 10. qx represents the mortality rate between age x and (x+1), that is the probability that a person aged x exact will die before reaching age (x+1). The data and problem is expressed as R code as follows:

```
library(dplyr)

    qxs <- tribble(
        ~age,  ~qx,
        0, 0.003536,
        1, 0.000213,
        2, 0.000127,
        3, 0.000098,
        4, 0.000068,
        5, 0.000086,
        6, 0.000082,
        7, 0.000062,
        8, 0.000064,
        9, 0.000053,
        10, 0.000064
    ) %>%
    mutate(
        survival_probability = 1 - qx
        , expected_payout = 100 * survival_probability
    )
    
    qxs
```

[image]

First question:

Can I simply calculate the survival probability as I did 1 - qx?

Second question, not sure if you can help, let us say some pension firm agrees to pay 100 dollars per month, can the expected payout simply be calculated as 100 * survival probability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your [data source](https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/birthsdeathsandmarriages/lifeexpectancies/datasets/nationallifetablesunitedkingdomreferencetables)

> $q_x$ is the mortality rate between age $x$ and $(x +1)$, that is the probability that a person aged $x$ exact will die before reaching age $(x +1)$.

Thus the answer to Question 1 is NO, assuming that you are calculating "survival probability" in the standard way as the fraction of an initial cohort (at `age = 0` here) still alive at a certain time. This requires an iterative combination of: calculating the fraction of the original cohort surviving at age $x$, multiplying that by $q_x$ to get the *fraction of the original cohort* the will die between ages $x$ and $(x +1)$, then calculating the fraction of the original cohort still alive at age $(x+1)$. To get you started:

At `age = 1` , the fraction still alive is $1-q_0=1-0.003536= 0.996464$. *Of that surviving fraction*, a fraction $q_1 = 0.000213$ will die before `age = 2`, for a fraction *of the original cohort* (at `age = 0`) dying between `age = 1` and `age = 2` of: $0.996464 * 0.000213 = 0.0002122$. So the fraction of the original cohort still alive at age 2 is 1 minus the fraction of the original cohort dying during each year of age: $1-0.003536-0.0002122=0.996252$. And so on ...

To check your calculations, note that the column `lx` in the original data table has those surviving as a function of time, expressed as the above fractions multiplied by 100,000.

With respect to question 2, the terminology "expected payout" typically means the average payout per person in the population. You thus need to calculate the mean lifetime from the entire survival distribution to get that expected payout.

These concepts can be very confusing. This [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis#General_formulation) is one place to start.

Comment: thanks. I will try to digest tomorrow. Indeed it is confusing.

Comment: actually reating this again can I simply use lx/100000 * payout then, to calculate the expected population payout at an age?

Comment: @cs0815 yes, _for any particular year of age_ that is correct. But the "expected payout" terminology usually applies to an average over a lifetime, or over what remains of a lifetime.

Comment: thanks. Sorry this is my clumsy terminology.